# How to change extension of certain files?

Tags: linux, command-line, file-rename

I have some files that look like below

```
user_conf_loc_week_en.json
user_conf_time_bf_week_en.json
user_conf_map_week_en.json
user_conf_pref_to_week_en.json
// some other files
```

I have some other files too in the directory but these are the ones I want to do an operation.

I need to change extension of files that start with `user_conf` and end with `_week_en.json`  to `.bk` such that my files now look like below

```
user_conf_loc_week_en.bk
user_conf_time_bf_week_en.bk
user_conf_map_week_en.bk
user_conf_pref_to_week_en.bk
```

I know how to change extension for all files

```
mv *.json *.bk
```

But I want to do it only for files that start with `user_conf` and end with `_week_en.json`

Comment: I am looking at a native command like (find, mv) instead of third party packages to do the operation. Is it possible?